# django-application in a sub-url

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I've got a problem when deploying a django-application to an apache-Server. The site should be accessible via `http://localhost/suburl/`.
I use a virtual environment.

The (shortened) virtualhost looks like that:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    [.. admin, documentroot, logfiles..]
    [.. static files alias ..]

    # WSGI-definitions:
    WSGIDaemonProcess spo python-path=/home/ai/project/source:/home/ai/project/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup spo
    WSGIScriptAlias /suburl /home/ai/project/source/django.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

The (standard) wsgi-file looks like that:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The result is:

Django does not create correct URLs, every URL is `http://localhost/path_to_view` instead of `http://localhost/suburl/path_to_view`. If I call the suburl manually, the sites are shown correctly.

I found some sources (e.g. http://www.normanmurrin.com/blog/2013/05/07/portable-django-apps/ ) that told me that mod_wsgi/django should support this out of the box. Well, it does. Except reverse() and the url-Tag.

Any ideas about the clue that makes it work?

Comment: How are you creating those URLs?

Comment: With named URLs in the {% url %} tag.

Comment: can you try "WSGIScriptAlias /suburl/ /home/ai/project/source/django.wsgi" instead of [...] /suburl [...]

Comment: This makes it even worse: Only the first page (/suburl/) can be opened. Opening /suburl/path_to_view/ results in Not Found (from the apache). Means that the request does not reach django...

Comment: Have you gone and set FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME in the Django settings file when you shouldn't have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue was FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME in the settings.py.

Thanks @Graham!